# Real time lighting in a 2D game with angled camera perspective

Tags: 2d, lighting, shading

The game "Monaco: What is yours is mine", has a nice real time lighting/shading effect as shown in this picture:
[image]

Notice how the vision is blocked by obstacles. I would be interested in seeing if this effect could work in a game with angled camera view. There are about a million such games, for example see Stardew Valley:

[image]

It is not clear to me if these two graphics styles could be easily combined. I'm looking for examples - either full games or just technical demos, etc. of the Monaco-like lighting effect applied to angled camera perspective (like in Stardew Valley).

Answer (score 3):

No, camera methods cannot be *easily* combined, but it is possible. One would have to make a 3d mapping of the area then make a birds view map from the 3d map, then make all of the blocked objects in the 2d bird map be darker in the 3d map, then use the 3d camera like in stardew Valley. BTW, Stardew valley is not actually 3d,it is simply .png's that are made to appear angled.